# How do I get send the int value of ScoreNum to another script?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this script to calculate the ScoreNum and I want to send the int value into another script. How should I connect the two?

```
public class QuizManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject Quiz1;
    public RadialBar Radial;
    int currentLevel; //to set how many levels are there


    public GameObject[] Levels;//array for the levels
    public float ScoreNum;

    public bool isSequence = true;

    void Start()
    {
        ScoreNum = 0;

        Quiz1.SetActive(true);
    }

  

    public void correctAnswer()
    {
        
        

            Levels[currentLevel].SetActive(false);//if the answer is wrong the question pop up will disable

            currentLevel++;
            Radial.Add(1);


            //if (isSequence)
           {
               ScoreNum += 1.0f;

               
           }
        //else if (!isSequence)
        {
            //ScoreNum += 0.5f;

        }


            Levels[currentLevel].SetActive(true);
        
    }

    public void wrongAnswer()
    {


        Levels[currentLevel].SetActive(false);//if the answer is wrong the question pop up will disable

        currentLevel++;
        Radial.Add(1);

        Levels[currentLevel].SetActive(true);
    }


}
```

I would like to then send the value into another script:

```
public class Results : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject ResultsStuff;
    public GameObject scoreText;
    public GameObject starOne;
    public GameObject starTwo;
    public GameObject starThree;
    public GameObject starOneEmpty;
    public GameObject starTwoEmpty;
    public GameObject starThreeEmpty;
    public float ScoreNum;

    //Audio

    public AudioSource audioSuccess;
    public AudioClip success;

    public AudioSource audioNt;
    public AudioClip nt;

    public AudioSource audioFail;
    public AudioClip fail;

    public AudioSource audioFilledappear;
    public AudioClip filledappear;

    public AudioSource audioEmptyappear;
    public AudioClip emptyappear;

    public float volume = 0.5f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        StartCoroutine("Stars");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    public IEnumerator Stars()
    {
        ResultsStuff.SetActive(true);
        scoreText.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = ScoreNum + "/28";

        if (ScoreNum == 0)
        {
            audioFail.PlayOneShot(fail, volume);
            starOne.SetActive(false);
            starTwo.SetActive(false);
            starThree.SetActive(false);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            audioEmptyappear.PlayOneShot(emptyappear, volume);
            starOneEmpty.SetActive(true);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            audioEmptyappear.PlayOneShot(emptyappear, volume);
            starTwoEmpty.SetActive(true);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            audioEmptyappear.PlayOneShot(emptyappear, volume);
            starThreeEmpty.SetActive(true);
        }

        else if (ScoreNum < 10)
        {
            audioNt.PlayOneShot(nt, volume);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            audioFilledappear.PlayOneShot(filledappear, volume);
            starOne.SetActive(true);
            starTwo.SetActive(false);
            starThree.SetActive(false);
            starOneEmpty.SetActive(false);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            audioEmptyappear.PlayOneShot(emptyappear, volume);
            starTwoEmpty.SetActive(true);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            audioEmptyappear.PlayOneShot(emptyappear, volume);
            starThreeEmpty.SetActive(true);
        }

        else if ((ScoreNum > 10) && (ScoreNum < 28))
        {
            audioNt.PlayOneShot(nt, volume);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            audioFilledappear.PlayOneShot(filledappear, volume);
            starOne.SetActive(true);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            audioFilledappear.PlayOneShot(filledappear, volume);
            starTwo.SetActive(true);
            starThree.SetActive(false);
            starOneEmpty.SetActive(false);
            starTwoEmpty.SetActive(false);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            audioEmptyappear.PlayOneShot(emptyappear, volume);
            starThreeEmpty.SetActive(true);
        }

        else if (ScoreNum == 28)
        {
            audioSuccess.PlayOneShot(success, volume);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            audioFilledappear.PlayOneShot(filledappear, volume);
            starOne.SetActive(true);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            audioFilledappear.PlayOneShot(filledappear, volume);
            starTwo.SetActive(true);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            audioFilledappear.PlayOneShot(filledappear, volume);
            starThree.SetActive(true);
            starOneEmpty.SetActive(false);
            starTwoEmpty.SetActive(false);
            starThreeEmpty.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Technically now, the results will always show 0 since the value of the integer has not been set on the second script. I'd be great if anyone could help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you were doing was trying to use two different variables as one. There are two ways to achieve what you need to do:

Method 1: (using only C#)

```
Defining the public float ScoreNum in QuizManager as static:

public class QuizManager : MonoBehaviour
    ....
    public static float ScoreNum;
    ....

Since you defined this variable as static, you can reach it from anywhere.

public class Results : MonoBehaviour
    ...
    // public float ScoreNum; //Delete this
    ...

    public IEnumerator Stars()
        ...
        if (QuizManager.ScoreNum == 0) //You reached the static ScoreNum value in the QuizManager script.
        ...
```

Method 2: (using Unity Inspector)

```
It looks like the method 1 actually.
To reach QuizManager script from Results class a variable should be added. So we can assign it in Unity Inspector.

public class Results : MonoBehaviour
    ...
    // public float ScoreNum; //Delete this
    public QuizManager quizManager; //Drag the QuizManager script here in the Inspector
    ...
    public IEnumerator Stars()
        ...
        if (quizManager.ScoreNum == 0) //Now you reached the ScoreNum value in the QuizManager script.
        ...
```

I suggest learning Singleton pattern for this kind of operations. Managers are usually unique in the game, and they are hold as DontDestroyOnLoad in Unity, and they are Singleton.